# JavaFX TextArea Odd Issue With Text Color

Tags: java, javafx, textarea

I'm having an interesting problem with an application I am writing.

The application is simple, it downloads log files via an HTTPS request and outputs the log file name and the saved location into a javaFX TextArea. Whenever I compile and run from IntelliJ, everything works as expected.
Whenever I build the program into a jar file and run it from the jar the text output within the TextArea is not readable.

What I mean is, if you highlight the entire TextArea and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> into a text editor you will see the output.

It seems that the font is setting itself to white?

has anyone ever experienced this problem before?

Thank you

Comment: Your application does not use custom font ? If so, where have you placed it and how you defined it ?

Comment: Are you using the same JDK version in IntelliJ as you are using when you run the jar file? Do you have a CSS file (or inline styles) defined on the text area? Can you reproduce this in a simple example (the fact that you are retrieving the text from somewhere is presumably irrelevant)?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a screen shot that shows your TextArea with all of its text selected.  Also, as BoHalim suggested, if you are using a custom font, add the code and/or FXML which loads the code and sets the TextArea’s font.

Comment: @James_D actually, on intellij I'm using 1.8 but most computers I've been testing on have 1.7, I did not put this into consideration. I didn't start seeing this issue on my machine until I started using 1.7.